# Xamarin.Forms - Image inside ViewCell flashes when updating the ItemSource

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on an Accordion ListView in a Xamarin.Forms project. This means that you can click on Category Headings in a ListView, which will expand or collapse the children beneath it.

There are two images and a title in each Category Heading so I am using a ViewCell. The issue is that when a Category is tapped and the children are shown, the images on the Category Heading ViewCell flash.

I have two observable collections that I am using to accomplish the Accordion Functionality. One that contains every parent (`MenuItemGroup`) and child (`MenuItem`) item, and one that only includes the `MenuItem`'s that should be shown. Every time a header is tapped, an event fires that gets the selected Index of the Category and toggles it's `Expanded` property (showing or hiding it's children). Then the `UpdateListContent()` method is called to refresh the ListView ItemSource:

```
    private ObservableCollection<MenuItemGroup> _allGroups;
    private ObservableCollection<MenuItemGroup> _expandedGroups;

    private void OnHeaderTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedIndex = _expandedGroups.IndexOf(
            ((MenuItemGroup)((StackLayout)sender).Parent.BindingContext));

        _allGroups[selectedIndex].Expanded = !_allGroups[selectedIndex].Expanded;

        UpdateListContent();
    }

    private void UpdateListContent()
    {
        _expandedGroups = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemGroup>();

        foreach (var group in _allGroups)
        {
            var newGroup = new MenuItemGroup(group.Title, group.CategoryIcon, group.Expanded);

            if (group.Count == 0)
            {
                newGroup.Expanded = null;
            }

            if (group.Expanded == true)
            {
                foreach (var menuItem in group)
                {
                    newGroup.Add(menuItem);
                }
            }
            _expandedGroups.Add(newGroup);
        }

        _menuItemListView.ItemsSource = _expandedGroups;
    }
```

Here is the DateTemplate and Image Binding:

```
        var menuItemGroupTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            var groupImage = new Image();
            groupImage.SetBinding<MenuItemGroup>(Image.SourceProperty, i => i.CategoryIcon);

            var titleLabel = new Label
            {
                TextColor = Color.White,
                VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label))
            };
            titleLabel.SetBinding<MenuItemGroup>(Label.TextProperty, t => t.Title);

            var stateIconImage = new Image
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand
            };
            stateIconImage.SetBinding<MenuItemGroup>(Image.SourceProperty, i => i.IconState);

            var menuItemGroupStackLayout = new StackLayout
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("40474d"),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                Padding = new Thickness(10 ,0, 20, 0),
                Children = { groupImage, titleLabel, stateIconImage }
            };

            var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();

            tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += OnHeaderTapped;
            tapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameter = menuItemGroupStackLayout.BindingContext;
            menuItemGroupStackLayout.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);

            var menuItemGroupViewCell = new ViewCell
            {
                View = menuItemGroupStackLayout,
                Height = 63.0
            };

            return menuItemGroupViewCell;
        });

        _menuItemListView = new ListView
        {
            RowHeight = 55,
            IsGroupingEnabled = true,
            ItemTemplate = menuItemTemplate,
            GroupHeaderTemplate = menuItemGroupTemplate,
            SeparatorColor = Color.FromHex("40474d"),
            HasUnevenRows = true
        };
```

Both the `groupIcon` and `stateIcon` images flash when the ListView ItemSource is updated. Can anyone offer any insight into how to fix this issue? Thanks!

I can post the `MenuItemGroup` and `MenuItem` classes if you think it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar problem when I tried to update my listview with images. I saw image flicker in Android. It is usually because of the delay in loading image.

Try fixing the image height and width. If that doesn't work, while updating the list content, update only the required images and textual values, so that all images need not load again.

I can provide a sample code if you really need it, since you only needed an insight.

So here's what you can do : 
Bind your Listview.Itemsource with _expandedGroups, so that you need not set the ItemsSource property everytime you expand/collapse. This refreshes your list and hence your images.

```
private ObservableCollection<MenuItemGroup> _expandedGroups;
public ObservableCollection<MenuItemGroup> ExpandedGroups
{
 get
 {
  return _expandedGroups;
 }
 set
 {
  if(value!=null) _expandedGroups = value;
  OnPropertyChanged("ExpandedGroups");
 }
}
```

And in your updation method : - Pass your allListSelection

```
UpdateListContent(_allGroups[SelectedIndex], SelectedIndex);
private void UpdateListContent(MenuItemGroup group, int index)
{
 if(group.Expanded)
 {
  foreach (var menuItem in group)
   {
     ExpandedGroup.Insert(index++, menuItem);
   }
 }
 else
 {
  foreach (var menuItem in group)
   {
     ExpandedGroup.Remove(menuItem); //Can also use ExpandedGroup.RemoveAt(index++);   
   }
  }
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you provide any sample code that demonstrates how to update the listview without updating the `groupImage`. The `groupImage` is different in each Menu Item Group Header so binding the SouceProperty is the only way I knew how to set each image

Comment: I have given a gist of what can be done. Modify as you require and check if this prevents your flicker.

Comment: Only a small flicker remained once I implemented the code to only update the section that would be changing. Once I added an image width and height the small flicker disappeared. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem.. Surprisingly the flicker totally disapeared after i've put the code that was notifying the control that update was needed inside the             Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread.